# Using Azure API Management service, how do I setup authentication for browser to API FrontEnd requests?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I realize that AZURE APIMS has a lot out of the box. Including subscription based server-side authentication.

However, I would like to know:
What options are available for client apps which are browsers?
For example,
Assume I have a single backend API with a single endpoint. I want to expose this endpoint to external business partners who use browser based applications which make requests to the backend from client side (browser)

How can I achieve this using AZURE API management service?

Answer (score 0):

APIM supports [protecting your API with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) which you can setup on your APIM instance and leverage in your browser-based applications.

Your application would first have to get the JWT token from your identity provider and then provide the same in requests to the APIM endpoint which are [pre-validated using a policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests).

[Here are samples of applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) using AzureAD (and its MSAL library) for authentication/authorization.

Comment: This is not necessarily the best option since our company does not manage the web app that makes requests to our backend. This is a third party app. I’m thinking I need a temp token approach